# IS_ROLEMEMBER not working properly

Tags: sql

I need to check whether a user has the role `DatabaseMailUserRole`.

I tried this:

```
SELECT IS_MEMBER('DatabaseMailUserRole')

SELECT IS_ROLEMEMBER ('DatabaseMailUserRole', '<loginname>')
```

Both return a value that is either `correct` or `incorrect`.

This means for several logins it returns the right value, but for others not.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: DatabaseMailUserRole is SQL-Server, to the best of my knowledge. Please tag with sql-server if so.

Answer (score 1):

DatabaseMailUserRole is sql server, from what i am aware of. An issue with your logic is that DatabaseMailUserRole is a database role, and therefore maps to *users*, not *logins*.

users (database level) and logins (server level) are distinct objects To access a database on a server, a user needs both a login name and a user name. Login and user objects for the same person may, but are not required to, share the same name

*For example*

```
CREATE USER someuser FROM LOGIN 'domain\login';
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'DatabaseMailUserRole','someuser';
GO

/* the following will fail because only users can be added to database role DatabaseMailUserRole */
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'DatabaseMailUserRole','domain\login';
GO  


EXECUTE AS login = 'domain\login'
SELECT IS_MEMBER('DatabaseMailUserRole') -> true

/* login 'domain\login' has username someuser */

SELECT CURRENT_USER -> 'someuser'
SELECT SYSTEM_USER ->  'domain\login'


SELECT IS_ROLEMEMBER ('DatabaseMailUserRole', 'domain\login') -> NULL
SELECT IS_ROLEMEMBER ('DatabaseMailUserRole', 'someuser') -> True
```

*Therefore* IS_ROLEMEMBER should get called w/ arguments as below:

```
SELECT IS_ROLEMEMBER ('DatabaseMailUserRole', '<user_name>')

/* where user name is one of the following */
SELECT name FROM sys.database_principals WHERE type=N'U'; 
/* OR */
SELECT USER_NAME()
/* OR */
SELECT CURRENT_USER
```

you might be getting correct results using logins names in some cases because server level logins can be mapped to a database level user with the same name.

Comment: The truth is that I ensured the users are created for all tested login for the database.

Comment: Furthermore, when I open login in ssms I can see the role DatabaseMailUserRole is set for the user in the db.

Comment: And you are passing usernames rather than login names to IS_ROLEMEMBER? Sry if you've already checked this, but your code implies that you are passing login name. Just want to eliminate the the simple before doing more research.